# How to set up Hardware RAID on Linux Server for Access from Windows as a NAS

Tags: linux, filesystems, windows, raid, nas

As I'm fairly new to Linux I wonder how to set up my RAID for network-wide access to use it as a NAS also from Windows.

I got a used Server with an **Adaptec 6405 Hardware RAID Controller** and added 4x 2TB Seagate SkyHawk HDDs. The setup of the RAID with the Hardware RAID Controller was pretty straightforward (I chose RAID 5).

To start the Server I installed **Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS** on a USB flash drive (will move to an SSD). From there I mounted the RAID which I currently set to ext4 filesystem and can now see it from the server side.

As I want to use the RAID as a NAS for all my data, I need to access it from Windows, ideally simply via File Explorer Network/$raidname. When all is set up and data transferred, I'll of course do a backup to store off-site as well, but first I need to be able to access it.

So my question is: ***What do I need to set up in order to use it from Windows?***

All help or links to threads I did not find is appreciated. Most threads I found dealt with the software RAID side of a software-based solution.

Comment: Ubuntu will see it has some resources including something that looks like a 6TB drive (Raid 5 gives you (n-1) drives worth of data). You have partitioned this disk, and created a filesystem which you can see. Now follow your threads to make part of your filestore available across the network. Where the storage comes from doesn't matter.  It could have come from 1 drive, it could have come from 100. As an analogy, use the fuel in your car to get your car to where you want it, don't worry about where the fuel came from

Comment: The typical software to make part of your linux filestore available to Windows is Samba, as I am sure your research will have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was easy. Just ignore the fact that it is a RAID, since the RAID functionality is handled by the RAID controller and is shown to Ubuntu/Linux as a single drive. Without this in search query you get much better search results. Then follow the steps to share a drive from Linux to the Network via *Samba* like here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba

Thanks to @icarus for this hint!